# Dagger singleton preloading

Tags: java, android, kotlin, singleton, dagger

I want to perform such functionality:

1. User opens first activity, and under the hood Dagger starts to initialize singleton, which I will inject on second activity
2. Navigates to the second activity, and here I inject this singleton to the activity

I've tried to just stupid inject this class to the first activity, but it not seems like a good solution

All that is needed because I want to perform some local database request in this singleton, and if it is not ready when activity has already started it can be a little bit confusing for user

Comment: If it's an asynchronous operation, there is no guarantee it will finish during the transition animation. Maybe show some loading thing while it's loading

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dependency to be available (=="preloaded") before the "second" `Activity` is started, you will have to `@Inject` this dependency somewhere else before. It can be the "first" `Activity` or e.g. the `Application` class.

In general it's not the best approach. It would be better if you weren't preloading dependencies, but loading them when they are actually needed. Loading one dependency can result in a whole spiral of dependency creation (hence the whole idea behind the dependency injection).